# /deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

Today when I tried to access my website it is showing following error on console

> /deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details

[image: error message]

When I follow the link it tells me:

> When a >>> combinator (or shadow-piercing descendant combinator) is encountered in a selector, replace every element in the selector match list with every element reachable from the original element by traversing any number of child lists or shadow trees.

But I don't understand what I should I change to fix this. What is the correct workaround for avoiding the error from function `querySelectorAll` when using the deprecated  `/deep/` combinator?

Comment: What did that link tell you?

Comment: "When a >>> combinator (or shadow-piercing descendant combinator) is encountered in a selector, replace every element in the selector match list with every element reachable from the original element by traversing any number of child lists or shadow trees." But i didn't understood it

Comment: I see that /deep/  on line 4222. Not sure  if that call is on the callstack when you hit this error but you might want to try to remove that and see if your site still works.

Comment: Where can i find that file?

Comment: I have no idea...do a search on your server? You are sure that script is coming from your site? It is not a plugin that went bad? Try to start chrome in incognito mode with plugins disabled.

Comment: I found the file name is i18n_template_no_process.js but i cant find it anywhere

Comment: Maybe it is not your website, but your browser that throws: https://1001-9732e57c756f-tainted-dot-chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/1062813007/

Comment: www.elementblue.com this is my site, could you plz look once in your console

Comment: your website isn't online: `connection reset`

Comment: I've just figured out the same problem which I had. I tried to set the source of an iFrame to undefined by an own created js file and then put it to a new display style. This messed up for me, maybe try looking for something like that.